# Empty Fields (Tabs) in DocuSign REST Integration from NetSuite

Tags: json, docusignapi, netsuite

I am pushing data out to DocuSign as part of a NetSuite integration. However, it seems like some of the tabs aren't getting populated even though I have been able to verify that the correct tab ID is getting passed in with the JSON data package. For example, this will leave an empty value:

```
{"value":"149.99","tabLabel":"Text 50d2801f-539e-4f7f-b6d0-81a8da39d5f9","locked":"true"}
```

But this will actually populate:

```
{"value":"49.99","tabLabel":"Text 204af852-0b2e-4f1b-9743-e9e3566994ea","locked":"true"}
```

In both cases they are "Text" type tabs, and both are there inside the container for text tab values. I feel like I may be missing something, but I don't know what. In comparing these two tabs, though, I can see one has no validation and the other has validation for "Numbers". The field with validation seems to be the one failing. I don't see any messages regarding whether or not this validation is failing the data or not, and the documentation for text tabs doesn't seem to provide any valuable insights.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I stumbled across something after hunting for a different piece of information... Apparently when a tab has predefined validation applied to it, it can effectively change the type of tab it is. This ultimately requires putting the tab data into a different spot in the JSON package. So, with the issue I had, the field that failed needed to be put into an array under the "numberTabs" attribute of the JSON package. This was not located anywhere I could see within the documentation. So, once I changed which bucket the tab data was added, it started populating in the document.

Hopefully this helps someone else having this issue.